# the executor of c language of code-runner outputs errors:& was unexpected at this time

Tags: visual-studio-code

i practice a simple input example in VS Code. like below:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
  char name[20];
  char surname[20];
  printf("Please input your name and surname,like: Jim  Green:");
  scanf("%s%s", name, surname);
  printf("%s,%s", name, surname);
  return 0;
}
```

**1st issue:**
the terminal outputs:

> h:\Vs-Code-C\cPrimerPlus\ch04>cd "h:\Vs-Code-C\cPrimerPlus\ch04" &&
> gcc 'ex01.c' -o 'ex01.exe' -Wall -g -O2 -static-libgcc -std=c11 &&
> &'"h:\Vs-Code-C\cPrimerPlus\ch04"ex01' & was unexpected at this time.

is there something wrong with my settings.json?

```
 "code-runner.runInTerminal": true, 
    "code-runner.executorMap": {
        "c": "cd $dir && gcc '$fileName' -o '$fileNameWithoutExt.exe' -Wall -g -O2 -static-libgcc -std=c11 && &'$dir$fileNameWithoutExt'",
        "cpp": "cd $dir && g++ '$fileName' -o '$fileNameWithoutExt.exe' -Wall -g -O2 -static-libgcc -std=c++17 && &'$dir$fileNameWithoutExt'"
        // "c": "cd $dir && gcc $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt.exe -Wall -g -O2 -static-libgcc -std=c11 -fexec-charset=GBK && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        // "cpp": "cd $dir && g++ $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt.exe -Wall -g -O2 -static-libgcc -std=c++17 -fexec-charset=GBK && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt"
    },
```

**2nd issue:**
settings.json .vscode
Problems loading reference

> 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/streetsidesoftware/cspell/cspell%404.0.53/cspell.schema.json#/definitions/DictionaryDefinition':
> Unable to load schema from
> 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/streetsidesoftware/cspell/cspell%404.0.53/cspell.schema.json':
> Request vscode/content failed unexpectedly without providing any
> details.

Comment: What is that `&` doing in front of `'$dir$fileNameWithoutExt'`

Comment: Oh,i see ,when i remove redundant & and redundant ' in '$fileName' , it can be run successful. but another warning appeared: implicit declaration of function 'scanf_s' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    scanf_s("%s%s", name, surname);

Comment: you don't use function `scanf_s`